# Wine crashes when I launch steam

Tags: 12.04, ati, wine, games, steam

When I start steam in wine, I see the log in screen, or if I have logged in already - the connecting account popup, I see this:

```
ntdll
ELF 7bcd0000-7bcfc000   Deferred        wine
Unhandled exception: page fault on write access to 0x00000000 in 32-bit code (0x7bc51b48).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:7bc51b48 ESP:0705b2cc EBP:0705b3b4 EFLAGS:00210216(  R- --  I   -A-P- )
 EAX:0000000c EBX:7bca6ff4 ECX:00000000 EDX:00000010
 ESI:0705b408 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0705b2cc:  0705b328 0705b320 7bc46923 00000030
0x0705b2dc:  00000000 0705b320 7bc68453 f777d6a0
0x0705b2ec:  00000000 3868af94 00000028 001b9a28
0x0705b2fc:  00110000 00000010 7bc3512f 0705b418
0x0705b30c:  00000000 0000035c 00000000 00110000
0x0705b31c:  7bca6ff4 0705b380 7bc472f3 00000000
Backtrace:
=>0 0x7bc51b48 NtAdjustPrivilegesToken+0xf8() in ntdll (0x0705b3b4)
  1 0x7ea03a4b AdjustTokenPrivileges+0x4a() in advapi32 (0x0705b3e4)
  2 0x3823574e in steamclient (+0x23574d) (0x0705b430)
  3 0x38236284 in steamclient (+0x236283) (0x0705b708)
  4 0x381e9739 in steamclient (+0x1e9738) (0x0705b770)
  5 0x381eb712 in steamclient (+0x1eb711) (0x0705b7a4)
  6 0x380ef0d9 in steamclient (+0xef0d8) (0x0705b90c)
  7 0x380efd3c in steamclient (+0xefd3b) (0x0705cad0)
  8 0x3845e818 in steamclient (+0x45e817) (0x0705cbe8)
  9 0x3845f140 in steamclient (+0x45f13f) (0x0705cc38)
  10 0x380efba6 in steamclient (+0xefba5) (0x0705de00)
  11 0x3849ddc7 in steamclient (+0x49ddc6) (0x0705e210)
  12 0x3849dfe4 in steamclient (+0x49dfe3) (0x0705e224)
  13 0x384506d9 in steamclient (+0x4506d8) (0x0705e448)
  14 0x3841cbf3 in steamclient (+0x41cbf2) (0x0705e46c)
  15 0x3846249c in steamclient (+0x46249b) (0x0705e478)
  16 0x38462123 in steamclient (+0x462122) (0x0705e504)
  17 0x3819af12 in steamclient (+0x19af11) (0x0705e574)
  18 0x3819b060 in steamclient (+0x19b05f) (0x0705e588)
  19 0x3f00ca4f in tier0_s (+0xca4e) (0x0705e5b8)
  20 0x3f00db0c in tier0_s (+0xdb0b) (0x0705e5dc)
  21 0x3f011b70 in tier0_s (+0x11b6f) (0x0705ea18)
  22 0x7bc71db0 call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0705ea28)
  23 0x7bc7486d call_thread_func+0x7c() in ntdll (0x0705eaf8)
  24 0x7bc71d8e RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0705eb18)
  25 0x7bc7a748 in ntdll (+0x6a747) (0x0705f368)
  26 0xf7616d4c start_thread+0xcb() in libpthread.so.0 (0x0705f468)
0x7bc51b48 NtAdjustPrivilegesToken+0xf8 in ntdll: movl  %edx,0x0(%edi)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (179 modules)
PE    400000-  63d000   Deferred        steam
PE   12d0000- 1387000   Deferred        sdl2
PE   45d0000- 46ea000   Deferred        chromehtml
PE   46f0000- 5acb000   Deferred        libcef
PE   7060000- 736d000   Deferred        steamservice
PE  10000000-100b4000   Deferred        crashhandler
PE  30000000-302c1000   Deferred        steam
PE  38000000-38881000   Export          steamclient
PE  3a000000-3aaf4000   Deferred        steamui
PE  3f000000-3f0ac000   Export          tier0_s
PE  3f200000-3f2b1000   Deferred        vgui2_s
PE  3f600000-3f64b000   Deferred        vstdlib_s
PE  3f800000-3f82e000   Deferred        filesystem_stdio
PE  4ad00000-4b67f000   Deferred        icudt
PE  60000000-60021000   Deferred        cserhelper
PE  65ec0000-66072000   Deferred        avcodec-53
PE  68b80000-68ba7000   Deferred        avutil-51
PE  6ab00000-6ab33000   Deferred        avformat-53
ELF 78d58000-78ed0000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 78ed0000-78f1e000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 78f20000-78f92000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 78f98000-78ffd000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-1.1.so
ELF 79108000-791fa000   Deferred        libasound.so.2
ELF 79328000-7933e000   Deferred        wbemprox<elf>
  \-PE  79330000-7933e000   \               wbemprox
ELF 79340000-79348000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 79348000-7b7fb000   Deferred        fglrx_dri.so
ELF 7b800000-7ba15000   Deferred        kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7ba15000   \               kernel32
ELF 7ba18000-7ba43000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7ba48000-7ba96000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7baa0000-7bab5000   Deferred        hid<elf>
  \-PE  7bab0000-7bab5000   \               hid
ELF 7bab8000-7bafb000   Deferred        dsound<elf>
  \-PE  7bac0000-7bafb000   \               dsound
ELF 7bc00000-7bcc3000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcc3000   \               alsa<elf>
  \-PE  7bce0000-7bcfc000   \               winealsa
ELF 7be08000-7be2b000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7be10000-7be2b000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7be30000-7be6e000   Deferred        rsaenh<elf>
  \-PE  7be40000-7be6e000   \               rsaenh
ELF 7be70000-7befd000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7be80000-7befd000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7bf00000-7bf04000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7bf10000-7bf1a000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7bf20000-7bf3d000   Deferred        pdh<elf>
  \-PE  7bf30000-7bf3d000   \               pdh
ELF 7bf40000-7bf5a000   Deferred        imagehlp<elf>
  \-PE  7bf50000-7bf5a000   \               imagehlp
ELF 7bf60000-7bf98000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7bf70000-7bf98000   \               usp10
ELF 7bf98000-7bfc3000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7bfa0000-7bfc3000   \               netapi32
ELF 7bfc8000-7c04c000   Deferred        urlmon<elf>
  \-PE  7bfd0000-7c04c000   \               urlmon
ELF 7c050000-7c0b7000   Deferred        setupapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c060000-7c0b7000   \               setupapi
ELF 7c2c0000-7c2c7000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7c2c8000-7c2d0000   Deferred        libjson.so.0
ELF 7c2d0000-7c2fc000   Deferred        secur32<elf>
  \-PE  7c2e0000-7c2fc000   \               secur32
ELF 7c408000-7c40f000   Deferred        libasound_module_pcm_pulse.so
ELF 7cf60000-7cfc6000   Deferred        libatiadlxx.so
ELF 7cfd0000-7cfe5000   Deferred        dhcpcsvc<elf>
  \-PE  7cfe0000-7cfe5000   \               dhcpcsvc
ELF 7d0e8000-7d101000   Deferred        libatiuki.so.1
ELF 7d108000-7d1f8000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d200000-7d218000   Deferred        userenv<elf>
  \-PE  7d210000-7d218000   \               userenv
ELF 7d218000-7d2d2000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7d230000-7d2d2000   \               opengl32
ELF 7d2d8000-7d2ec000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d2e0000-7d2ec000   \               msimg32
ELF 7d2f0000-7d312000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d300000-7d312000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7d318000-7d333000   Deferred        spoolss<elf>
  \-PE  7d320000-7d333000   \               spoolss
ELF 7d338000-7d341000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d348000-7d34d000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7d350000-7d399000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7d3a0000-7d3b2000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7d3b8000-7d43d000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.11
ELF 7d440000-7d452000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.3
ELF 7d458000-7d480000   Deferred        libk5crypto.so.3
ELF 7d480000-7d54f000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.3
ELF 7d550000-7d614000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.26
ELF 7d6e0000-7d71e000   Deferred        libgssapi_krb5.so.2
ELF 7d720000-7d773000   Deferred        libcups.so.2
ELF 7d778000-7d7b2000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7d780000-7d7b2000   \               winspool
ELF 7d7b8000-7d897000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7d7c0000-7d897000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7d898000-7d950000   Deferred        crypt32<elf>
  \-PE  7d8a0000-7d950000   \               crypt32
ELF 7d950000-7d9fd000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7d960000-7d9fd000   \               winmm
ELF 7dd00000-7dd21000   Deferred        localspl<elf>
  \-PE  7dd10000-7dd21000   \               localspl
ELF 7dd28000-7dd50000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7dd30000-7dd50000   \               msacm32
ELF 7dd50000-7dd6e000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7dd78000-7dd7c000   Deferred        libkeyutils.so.1
ELF 7dd80000-7dd89000   Deferred        libkrb5support.so.0
ELF 7dd90000-7dda8000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7dde8000-7ddfa000   Deferred        libavahi-client.so.3
ELF 7de00000-7de07000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7de10000-7de15000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF 7de18000-7de26000   Deferred        libavahi-common.so.3
ELF 7de28000-7de60000   Deferred        winhttp<elf>
  \-PE  7de30000-7de60000   \               winhttp
ELF 7de60000-7debe000   Deferred        dbghelp<elf>
  \-PE  7de70000-7debe000   \               dbghelp
ELF 7dec0000-7dee6000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7ded0000-7dee6000   \               mpr
ELF 7dee8000-7df57000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7def0000-7df57000   \               wininet
ELF 7df58000-7df6c000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7df60000-7df6c000   \               psapi
ELF 7df88000-7dfbc000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7df90000-7dfbc000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7dfc0000-7dfc6000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dfc8000-7dfd3000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7e0c0000-7e0ea000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7e0f0000-7e124000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7e128000-7e138000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7e138000-7e13c000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7e140000-7e149000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e150000-7e15a000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e160000-7e166000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e168000-7e16c000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7e170000-7e192000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e180000-7e192000   \               imm32
ELF 7e198000-7e19f000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e1a0000-7e1a4000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7e1a8000-7e1c9000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e1d0000-7e1ea000   Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF 7e1f0000-7e324000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e328000-7e33a000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e360000-7e3f3000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e370000-7e3f3000   \               winex11
ELF 7e3f8000-7e40e000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e410000-7e4aa000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e4b0000-7e4b6000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7e4b8000-7e4c1000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF 7e4d0000-7e545000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e4e0000-7e545000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e548000-7e650000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7e560000-7e650000   \               ole32
ELF 7e650000-7e742000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7e670000-7e742000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7e748000-7e7b2000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e760000-7e7b2000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e7b8000-7e9c9000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e7c0000-7e9c9000   \               shell32
ELF 7e9d0000-7ea30000   Dwarf           advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9e0000-7ea30000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea30000-7eaed000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea40000-7eaed000   \               gdi32
ELF 7eaf0000-7ec30000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb00000-7ec30000   \               user32
ELF 7ec30000-7ed28000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec40000-7ed28000   \               comctl32
ELF 7ed28000-7ed5a000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7ed30000-7ed5a000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7ed60000-7ed6d000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed70000-7ed8a000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ed90000-7eda9000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eda0000-7eda9000   \               version
ELF 7efb0000-7efdc000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe0000-7efec000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eff0000-7eff9000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7458000-f745d000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7460000-f760a000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7610000-f762b000   Dwarf           libpthread.so.0
ELF f7650000-f7792000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7798000-f77ba000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77bc000-f77bd000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001c    0
    00000019    0
    00000014    0
    00000013    0
0000001a plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001b    0
00000021 explorer.exe
    00000022    0
00000023 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\Steam.exe
    0000002c    0
    00000009    0
    0000000b    0
    00000047    0
    00000046    0
    00000045    0
    00000044    0
    00000043    0
    00000042    0
    00000041    0 <==
    0000003f    0
    0000003e    0
    0000003d    0
    0000003c    0
    0000003b    0
    0000003a    0
    00000039    0
    00000038    0
    00000037    0
    00000036    0
    00000035    0
    00000034    0
    00000033    0
    00000032    0
    0000002f    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000028    0
    00000024    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.4
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 3.8.0-34-generic
```

It happened really suddenly, I had steam working in wine perfectly, and I was even able to play portal 2, then I installed Borderlands 2 and it for some reason couldn't install some directx package. Then I rebooted my computer, and steam on wine didn't work. Maybe borderlands broke it or something? Thanks for any help!

Specs:

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (64bit)
AMD Athlon(tm) X4 760K Quad Core Processor × 4 
Radeon HD 7770 GPU
MSI FM2-A75MA-E35 (motherboard)
Wine build: wine-1.4

Answer (score 2):

This could be related to a Steam update. I was using Wine 1.5 up until recently. Steam released an update a couple of weeks ago and once I had put it in, I was getting a similar page fault exception. Wine released 1.7.8 a few days later and once I moved to that Steam started working.

Comment: This is exactly the case. Requires a wine update.